# If $PA\sin A+PC\sin C=PB\sin B+PD\sin D$, are $A,B,C,D$ concyclic?

Tags: geometry

> $ABCD$ is a convex quadrangle, and $$PA\cdot\sin A+PC\cdot\sin C=PB\cdot\sin B+PD\cdot\sin D.$$
> Here $P = AC \cap BD$, $\sin A$ means $\sin \angle DAB$, $\sin B$ means $\sin \angle ABC$, $\sin C$ means $\sin \angle BCD$, $\sin D$ means $\sin \angle CDA$.
>
> [image]
>
> Are $A,B,C,D$ concyclic?

Conversely, when $A,B,C,D$ are concyclic, it is easy to know $PA\cdot\sin A+PC\cdot\sin C=PB\cdot\sin B+PD\cdot\sin D$. But this, is it true?